# MySQL variables not available immediately

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following SQL which has to be run twice in order for the "duration_in_queue" to populated with values other than NULL.

I assume that the SQL variables are not being set or stored?

I have been at it for hours trying to find a solution to no avail and hoping that someone here can help :)

```sql
SELECT
    DATE(pm.rstdtime) AS cntldate,
    sh.sd_no,
    sh.work_group,
    ROUND(
        IF (
            @sd_id = sh.sd_no,
            (
                TIMESTAMPDIFF(
                    SECOND,
                    @dt,
                    sh.data_entry_dtime
                ) / 86400
            ) * 86400 + LEAST(0, @dt := sh.data_entry_dtime),
            NULL + LEAST(0, @sd_id := sh.sd_no) + (@dt := sh.data_entry_dtime)
        )
    ) AS duration_in_queue
FROM
    p_master pm
LEFT JOIN s_history sh ON pm.sd_no = sh.sd_no,
 (SELECT(@sd_id := 0)) AS a
WHERE
    sh.log_text IN (
        'Created',
        'Dispatched',
        'Restored'
    )
AND CONVERT_TZ(
    sh.data_entry_dtime,
    'GMT',
    'Australia/NSW'
) <= pm.rstdtime
ORDER BY
    sh.sd_no,
    sh.data_entry_dtime,
    sh.log_text
LIMIT 10
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that the SQL variables are not being set or stored?

This is likely correct.

According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html):

> As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. You might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined and may change based on the elements contained within a given statement; in addition, this order is not guaranteed to be the same between releases of the MySQL Server.

Comment: Hi ruakh, I did read that but isnt "(SELECT(@sd_id := 0)) AS a" setting the @variable. I also tried putting a SELECT * FROM (above query) and it didnt change a thing :(

Comment: @mybigman: About the only guarantees with `@sd_id := 0` are (1) that it evaluates to `0` and (2) that it will set `@sd_id` to `0` sometime before the next SQL query you run using the same database connection. In particular, there is *no* guarantee that it will set `@sd_id` to `0` at any predictable point during the execution of this query.